# How to fix EF Core for adding non existent column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm a bit new to Entity Framework Core. So I'm trying to do a insert using EF Core but I get an exception 
 such as

```
SqlException: Invalid column name 'UsersUserId'.
```

Which used to be on my table. I removed it because it was not longer necessary.
After I ran a few Unit Test and the Exception return as the one above, I drop the table from the database and actually create a branch new table with a different name. But, I still getting same error when trying to insert records.

This is the query generated by EF Core

```
DECLARE @p0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p1 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p2 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p3 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p4 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p0 = NULL;
SET @p1 = NULL;
SET @p2 = NULL;
SET @p3 = NULL;
SET @p4 = NULL;

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StorePairing] ([CreatedDate], [FullName], [SessionId], [StoreId], [UsersUserId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);
SELECT [StorePairId]
FROM [dbo].[StorePairing]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [StorePairId] = scope_identity();
```

The last column UserUserId is not longer anywhere in the database or in code. I'm using code first approch so I don't if I need to do some special flushing.

So, How to fix EF Core for adding non existent column?

Comment: Have a look in the migrations and snapshot files, chances are it's still present there as a string in a create table command.

Comment: It seems that Ef core create sql command based on your defined relationships . Check relationships structure between classes. can you share classes here defined on context?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the relationship on other entity class fixes the problem